# Remove last character if it is number from data frames that are stored as a values of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I wrote the code as follows to remove last character of Data Frames columns if it is number. Data Frames are stored as a values of dictionary in python and their name as a key of dictionary. my code doesn't produce the right result, how should I develop it?

```
for key,val in df.items():
    if key != "name1":
        for col in val.columns:
            m = re.search(r'\d+$', col)
            if m is not None:
                col = col[:-1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code by just replacing a single digit at the end of a column name with an empty string. This will not affect any values that don't end with a digit:

```py
for key, val in df.items():
    if key != "name1":
        val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'\d$', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I do it, if I want to remove last two numbers of string ? for if if key == "name1":

Comment: @ella you can do the same thing, just change the regex to match two trailing digits i.e. `val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'\d\d$', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Maybe I need to open another question, but just a small question, how can I remove all "_"  JUST before the number that we remove if there is exist any, not all "_"

Comment: should be like thsi         **val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'_\d$', '', regex=True)**

Comment: yes I think it should be like this :
**val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'\d$', '', regex=True)
   val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'_$', '', regex=True)**

Comment: @ella yes, if you want to remove an `_` before the last digit, if it exists, then `val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'_\d$', '', regex=True)` should be right; if you use the two step process, that will remove an `_` at the end, regardless of whether there were any digits there originally or not.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided is not modifying the column names of the data frames because you are modifying the col variable, which is just a copy of the actual column name. To modify you can use `rename()` method:

```
for key, val in df.items():
    if key != "name1":
        renamed_cols = {}
        for col in val.columns:
            m = re.search(r'\d+$', col)
            if m is not None:
                new_col_name = col[:-1]
                renamed_cols[col] = new_col_name
        val = val.rename(columns=renamed_cols)
        df[key] = val
```